# Jenkins Relaunch Slave Agent via SSH oddity

Tags: ssh, jenkins, agent

Occasionally, one of my Jenkins slave agents will be marked as offline by Jenkins. 
The agent is actually running just fine, but the Jenkins server can't seem to ssh to it.  Relaunching the slave agent yields nothing more than an empty log console.

A really weird and odd workaround for this issue is the following:

1. configure the slave agent to use an incorrect IP address
2. relaunch the slave agent (at this point, there may be a couple log lines indicating an ssh attempt)
3. configure the slave agent again and this time use the correct IP address
4. relaunch the slave agent

That seems to fix the issue every single time.  Has anyone experienced this and know of a better solution?

Comment: The workaround does seem to work for me as well; still curious on the actual way to fix this though.

Comment: I'm curious what version of Jenkins you're using.  Are you using the Long Term Support Release (1.580)?  I can reproduce this issue (and the fix) on 1.562.

Comment: @greenhat I'm using 1.565.3

Answer (score 1):

I encountered something similar on Jenkins 2.222.3. After an outage, most nodes recovered and were reconnected to the master, but a couple of them did not. I rebooted the failing slave machines, which did not help at all.
I compared the configuration of the good and the failing slaves, examined connecticity / firewall etc.
The only sign of difference was that according to the master log, after the outage, the "good" slaves tried to reconnect multiple times, as several of the following log messages were present:

> Attempting to reconnect slavexxx

The failing slaves had only one of the above log message. (Note: I checked the Advanced part of the node configuration, namely retry count and retry interval. All slaves were using the same default values for these settings.)

Looks like a couple of slaves got stuck on the first retry, and remained in some kind of infinite loop.

Maybe restarting Jenkins would have fixed it, but luckily I found a lighter workaround: I changed the *Remote root directory* setting from /foo/bar/ to /foo/bar or vice versa. Yes, I only changed the trailing /, so the new and the old path remains semantically the same. Still Jenkins probably sensed that a change in the remote root dir was a good enough reason to abort an ongoing reconnect process and start a fresh one.

**YMMV**